# Instagram API not pull all data in one request

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

When i am requesting for the data of specific tag, it's not giving me all image from Instagram.
with the below URL i am trying to access data.

URL:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/followme/media/recent?client_id=[client_ID]&access_token=[token]&callback=?
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: That endpoint is meant to *"Get a list of **recently** tagged media"* i don't see one that returns them all (and didn't expect to).

Comment: is there any way to get all images with specific tag in intagram, can you please help me how to do this...

Comment: Do you see a way in the API? http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ How many results would you expect to get with the tag `cat`?

Comment: Getting ALL images would be a huge request, so it won't give you everything at once. But according to the API, you can specify a `min_id` to get older results one page at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the Instagram API documentation at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

You can pull media (images and video) for a given tag with the tags/media/recent endpoint. It would look something like this for retrieving media with the tag "eggs":

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/eggs/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&count=50
```

You will need to use the pagination property in the response for paging through results. Look for the next_url property in the pagination object for the next url to call.

You can add a count parameter to your call to specify the number of records to receive for each call. This count parameter has a maximum value of 50 I think, I can't remember the exact number.